# Unwrapping Optional Entity

Tags: swiftui, core-data

Let's say that `Item` is a CoreData entity:

```
struct ItemDetailView: View {
@Binding var item: Item?
@Binding var isEditing: Bool

var body: some View{
    if isEditing {
        TextField( "Name", text: Binding($item.data)! )
    }else{
        Text(item!.data!)
    }
}
}
```

**Error**: Value of optional type 'Item?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'data' of wrapped base type 'Item'

---

**Edit** All the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ItemDetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item?
    @Binding var isEditing: Bool
    
    var body: some View{
        if isEditing {
            
            TextField( "Name", text: Binding($item.data)! )
        }else{
            Text(item!.data!)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemEditorView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    let isNew: Bool
    @State var isEditing: Bool = false
    @State var item: Item?
    @Binding var newItem: Item?
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if isNew {
                
        }
        
        NavigationView{
            ItemDetailView(item: isNew ? $newItem : $item, isEditing: $isEditing)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button(isNew ? "Add" : (isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit")) {
                            //TBI
                            if isNew {
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement:.cancellationAction){
                        Button("Cancel"){
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Item Editor")
        }
    }
}

struct ItemsListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.data, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    @State var presentNewItemEditorView = false
    @State var newItem: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Text(newItem?.data ?? "nil")
                List {
                    ForEach(items){ item in
                        NavigationLink(item.data!, destination: ItemEditorView(isNew: false, item:item, newItem: $newItem))
                    }
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presentNewItemEditorView, content: {
                ItemEditorView(isNew: true, isEditing: true, newItem: $newItem)
            })
            .navigationTitle("Main")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button("New goal"){
                        presentNewItemEditorView = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .task {
                newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
                newItem!.data = "New item text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `item` optional? `@Binding var item: Item` compiles. By the way `@Binding` is for value types. A Core Data entity can/should be *bound* as `@ObservableObject`.

Comment: added all the code to show you why is `item` optional

Comment: Please watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8rqjs_CNsk) how to use Core Data in SwiftUI efficiently for adding and editing items without optionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation by [Conny Wals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8rqjs_CNsk) sugested by @vadian

```
    import CoreData
    class EditViewModel {
        /// **new** instance of item to edit. Don't edit the item, if any, that we pass to VM
        var item: Item4
        /// Context to use in the isolated changes
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext
        
        /// Pass an item if  you want to edit one, or nil to generate one
        init(item: Item4? = nil){
            self.context = PersistenceController.shared.childViewContext()
            if let item = item {
                self.item = PersistenceController.shared.copyForEditing(of: item, in: context)
            } else {
                self.item = PersistenceController.shared.newTemporaryInstance(in: context)
            }
        }
        
        func persist(){
            PersistenceController.shared.persist(item)
        }
    }

    import SwiftUI

    struct EditItemView: View {
        @State var viewModel: EditViewModel
        @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack{
                    
                    TextField( "Item Name", text: Binding(get: {viewModel.item.name ?? ""}, set: {viewModel.item.name = $0}))
                    
                    
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Edit Item")
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Cancel"){
                    dismiss()
                }, trailing: Button("Save"){
                    viewModel.persist()
                    dismiss()
                })
            }
        }
    }

    struct ItemsView04: View {
        @FetchRequest(
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item3.name, ascending: true)],
            animation: .default)
        private var items: FetchedResults<Item4>
        
        @State var editItemViewIsPresent = false
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                List {
                    ForEach(items){ item in
                        NavigationLink(item.name ?? ""){
                            EditItemView(viewModel: EditViewModel(item: item))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button {
                            editItemViewIsPresent = true
                        }label:{
                            Text("+")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $editItemViewIsPresent){
                    EditItemView(viewModel: EditViewModel())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I it unclear what are you trying to achieve. Here are options that will compile.

### Value type

```
struct Item {
    var data: String
}

struct ItemDetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    @Binding var isEditing: Bool
    
    var body: some View{
        if isEditing {
            TextField( "Name", text: Binding(projectedValue: $item.data) )
        }else{
            Text(item.data)
        }
    }
}
```

### Reference type and value type

```
class Item {
    var data: String? = ""
}

struct ItemDetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item? // Has no sense, because @Binding does't work with clsses!
    @Binding var isEditing: Bool
    
    var body: some View{
        if isEditing {
            TextField("Name", text: Binding(get: {
                item!.data!
            }, set: { value in
                item?.data = value
            }))
        } else {
            Text(item!.data!)
        }
    }
}
```